# Linq: Return results count for large dataset

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have IEnumerable that is result of database query that has a large dataset, as much as 10000 records.  I need the count to display on the webpage for pagination. How can I do it, using `.Count()` will result in exceptions like 1The underlying provider failed on Open` or takes way too long.

Is there a way I can query database to get the count for results by linq-sql?

Comment: If you're saying it times out, I would suspect it's an IQueryable, not a regular in memory IEnumerable (it's the query, not the result set)....meaning it's the DB call that's timing out....in which case, you should optimize your query, or increase the timeout value in your connection string in your app/web.config.

Comment: Its not the timeout from DB, DB returned the results in the IEnumerable Obj, and I am trying to count them

Comment: @remo Please trying adding .ToList to your IEnumerable, if it times out too it means the collection is lazily loaded

Comment: @vc 74 ToList() is resulted in `The underlying provider failed on Open`

Comment: @remo Immediately or after a delay?

Comment: See @uadrive's answer. Did you check the SQL that runs?

Comment: assuming you are using sql server, you could use the sql profiler to see exactly what runs (or whatever the equivalent is for your database) or use something like the linq to sql profiler from ayende http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/UberProf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be how you are using LINQ.  if you call the query like this:

```
var users = (from u in context.Users select u);
int userCount = users.Count();
```

That would effectively only call a query to return a count from the database.  If you did something like this:

```
List<User> users = (from u in context.Users select u).ToList();
int userCount = users.Count();
```

That would call and retrieve the records from the database then try to count them.

Answer (score 2):

let the database tell you the count - databases are built to be able to do this - and select only the rows you need from the database instead of returning the whole set from the database when you only want to use a small subset.

Comment: Can linq-sql just query for count from database? B/w i have optimized query and i need to display large dataset

Comment: in the question, i didn't realize you were talking about linq to sql.  i haven't had much experinece with it, but yes, my understanding is that calling Count before doing any enumeration or such things should send a count query to the database rather than returning a whole result set from the database.  linq uses deferred execution such that it doesn't actually enumerate the list (or send the query to database) until you call something to loop over or aggregate or something first() or the like so that it can limit the result set with all the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a select count query first, but then some data might have been added or deleted. Wrap it in a transaction, and you'll have a huge locking issue.

Another way would be to get page 1, and then get the rest in batches on another thread, when that finishes update the count and display, you could even have a running count, to indicate progress in getting all the data.

Why are you getting all the records at once?

If you looked at it as getting the first, last, previous and next page.
And then dealt with issues that arise from that approach, you'd have a scalable solution.

The reason count is taking so long is it has to suck all 10,000 records into the client in order to count them.
It's a solution that will scale very badly, imagine a 100,000 or a million!
The other point is latency. Those 100,000 are at the time the query was executed, refresh isn't going to be popular is it. Then  when you do refresh, you have all the display the page you were on issues...

If you reworked it to get the next n records after the the last one currently displayed or before the first...
Then you could cache, you could refresh pages in the background, you could attempt to predict request, say get the next n pages in advance.